# Tabular Forms Column merging Oracle Apex 5

Tags: oracle-apex, tabular

Does anybody know how to merge two columns of tabular form into a single column?

This is an example:

[image]

Comment: the image posted doesn't really explain what will happen to the values of the two columns merged.does it concatenate the values or does it add them up?you have to explain further what you really want to do with it if you want to gain some answer.

Comment: Try a Master - Detail form http://docs.oracle.com/html/E39147_04/app_forms003.htm

Comment: Hi dear, about the values i have created a pl/sql process which saves the values, it actually add up, what i want is making space in the page as it now exceeds the page and also i want to name the two cols one name, as it is in picture number 2

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by applying html codes in your query.
Try this in your query

```
SELECT attendance,
       member_id,
       name,
       saving,
       '<input class=''u-TF-item u-TF-item--text '' style=''text-align:center;'' name=''repayment'' value='||repayment||'></input>'||'<br>'||
       '<input class=''u-TF-item u-TF-item--text '' style=''text-align:center;'' name=''profit'' value='||profit||'></input>' repayment,
FROM
       your_table
WHERE
...
```

- assuming that their header is the same as their column name;
- class was just copied from the other column to match their appearance.